# Bukkit - Aquiring explanition for why enums is not working

Tags: java, enums, bukkit

I would like to make it so I can put integers defined by when I calling  new Objectives(new Runnable(), "name here", int x, int y, int z) but I cant seem to do it. Again, the ints in the ENUMS will be put there when calling a new Objectives and the Location

Here's my code so far:

```
package me.terturl.com.Objectives;

public enum Objectives {
MECH(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}, "Mech", Location loc, int x, int y, int z);

private String name;
private Location loc;
private int x;
private int y;
private int z;

public objectives(Runnable run, String name, Location loc, int x, int y, int z) {
    this.name = name;
    this.loc = loc;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Location getLoc() {
    return loc;
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? Also, shouldn't the o in objectives be capitalized here: `public objectives(...`?

Answer (score 1):

All `enum`s are **constants**. You cannot specify parameters for new instances of an `enum`. Instead, use a class to construct new objects based on the given parameters.

Example of an `enum` in usage:

```
enum WeekDay { MONDAY(1), TUESDAY(2), WEDNESDAY(3), THURSDAY(4), FRIDAY(5), SATURDAY(6), SUNDAY(0); public final int id; WeekDay(int id){ this.id = id; } }
```

Example of a `class` that may be used for this case:

```
package me.terturl.com.Objective;

import org.bukkit.Location;

public class Objective {

  private String name;
  private Location loc;
  private int x, y, z;

  Objective(Runnable run, String name, Location loc, int x, int y, int z) {
    this.name = name;
    this.loc = loc;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

  public String getName() { return name; }

  public Location getLoc() { return loc; }

}
```

**Edit: All** `enum`s implicitly extend `java.lang.Enum`. Since Java does not support multiple inheritance, an `enum` cannot extend anything else. Hence, `enum`s will not achieve what you are looking for - Storing details of an objective. Instead use the above class and create a *Manager Class* to handle your objectives.

However, `enum`s can `implement` `interfaces`, when applicable:

```
interface MajorObjectWrapper{
  public Object getMajorObject();
}

enum Utility implements MajorObjectWrapper {
  VAULT("Gold"),
  //...
  LOCK(new Lock());
  
  @Override public Object getMajorObject(){ return obj; }
  
  private Object obj;
  
  Utility(Object obj){ this.obj=obj };

}

{
  MajorObjectWrapper wrapper=Utility.VAULT;
  System.out.println(wrapper.getMajorObject());
  // You will get: "Gold"! :)
}
```

- Thanks to **@nrubin29** for citation on `implement`ing `interface`s with `enum`s.

> Specified by:
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

**PS:** Your package declaration makes the absolute path of the class `me.terturl.com.Objectives.Objectives`. Consider refactoring the package declaration as `me.terturl.com` or `me.terturl.com.objectives`. Semantics :)

Comment: All `enum`s are still `Object`s. Also, you might want to mention that you can `implement` `interface`s with `enum`s. Also, as far as the package declaration, it should be `tld.domain.project` like `me.terturl.objectives` or `com.terturl.objectives`.

Comment: @nrubin29 Actually, the use of Maven allows one to use group ID as the package declaration unless necessary. So both `tld.domain` and `tld.domain.project` should be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an `enum` is what you're looking for. From the Oracle Java tutorial's `enum` page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants.

Constants. So making new instances really doesn't make sense. And that's also enforced at the language level. JLS section 8.9.2:

> It is a compile-time error if a constructor declaration in an enum declaration is public or protected (§6.6).
>
> In an enum declaration, a constructor declaration with no access modifiers is private.

So there's your first problem. You can't have a `public` enum constructor.

---

Second, you're slightly misunderstanding how enum constant constructors work. When you do something like

```
MECH(...)
```

You're effectively *calling* a constructor. And you can't do things like have `int x` in a constructor call. You're going to have treat it like any other constructor, which means either you get to put a method call there or some other expression that evaluates to something. Your first two parameters were OK, but the rest of them, not so much.

For example, if I wanted to make a `new String()`, I can't do this:

```
String s = new String(String putStringHere);
```

Similar logic applies to your code.

Honestly, I'm a little confused why you're using an `enum`. Seems to me like a regular old class would do just fine.

(also, probably a typo, but your constructor should be capitalized)

Comment: Well I want to be able to have multiple objectives, the mech is an objective, in one class and be able to getCurrentObjective(), getObjectiveLocation(), getObjectiveName(), and getObjectiveDistance().

Comment: Is this objective going to be constant, or might its location and such change?